# Postfix conditional operator in F#

Tags: f#, postfix-operator

In Perl language one can write something like

```
someFunction() if $x == 0
```

i.e. apply condition in postfix notation.

I was sure there must be similar type of expression in F#, since it is so flexible in working with functions. But when I try to write

```
someFunction() if x = 0
```

or

```
someFunction() << if x = 0
```

I recieve an expected error message. Is there any way to implement more or less general postfix conditional operator in F#?

Comment: What I am thinking of is something like `let iif condition call prms = if condition then call prms else ()` but I can't plug anything into it )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no built-in F# support for this and so I would recommend just using the normal prefix style conditionals (or pattern matching). There is also no standard operator/function that would be common in the community, so the idiomatic style would just use ordinary `if`.

I think that the best you can do is something like this:

```
/// Evaluates lazy value only if the specified boolean holds
let assuming b (v:Lazy<_>) = if b then v.Value

// Print foo only when x > 40
let foo() = printfn "hi"
let x = 42
lazy foo() |> assuming (x > 40)
```

Note that I had to add `lazy` to the expression (to make sure it is not actually evaluated when the condition does not holds). This works, but it is certainly uglier than writing `if x>40 then foo()` - but it is a fun thing to experiment with :-)

Comment: Thanks Tomas, that indeed does the trick. P.S. Let me thank you for your Real-World Functional Programming book, it's awesome.